# how to get Xml out put in rest webservices in zf2?

Tags: php, web-services, rest, zend-framework2

i  m creating restful web services in zf2

In zend fram work 
return new JsonModel(array(
            'data' => $data,
        ));

for json out put

but i want output should be in xml.
what shoud i do for this?